# cannot convert <int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘int*'

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, compiler-errors

I am trying to find lower and upper bound of an element by using pair.first and pair.second

I am getting following error while compiling using gcc:

```
zco.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
zco.cpp:136:47: error: cannot convert 
‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘int*’ in 
initialization
int *a = lower_bound(x.begin(), x.end(),temp1);
                                           ^
zco.cpp:137:47: error: cannot convert 
‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘int*’ in 
initialization
int *b = upper_bound(y.begin(), y.end(),temp2);
```

code:

```
int main(){
    int N,X,Y;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&N,&X,&Y);
    vector< pair<int,int> > n(N);
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int temp1,temp2;
        scanf("%d %d",&temp1,&temp2);
        n[i] = make_pair(temp1,temp2);
    }
    vector<int> x(X);
    for(int i=0;i<X;i++){
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }
    vector<int> y(Y);
    for(int i=0;i<Y;i++){
        scanf("%d",&y[i]);
    }
    stable_sort(n.begin(), n.end());
    stable_sort(x.begin(), x.end());
    stable_sort(y.begin(), y.end());
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int temp1 = n[i].first;
        int temp2 = n[i].second;
        int *a = lower_bound(x.begin(), x.end(),temp1);
        int *b = upper_bound(y.begin(), y.end(),temp2);
        sum += b-a+1;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

How can I solve this error. Please help me.

Comment: `a` and `b` types are wrong, `lower_bound` returns an iterator, not a pointer, you can fix it without much problem using automatic type deduction: `auto a(lower_bound(x.begin(), x.end(), temp1));`

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` in c++ code?

Comment: @Ed.  Most college professors still teach C++ as if it was C, teaching student to write code that's exactly like what many of us spend our days cleaning up.

Comment: Those that can can, those who can't teach. That is a quote from someone. Anyway they could at least tell their charges to check the return value

Comment: They still do check the return of `new`, for some obscure reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to convert an iterator to a pointer, first dereference the iterator, which will yield a reference (to int, in your case), and then get the address of the value referenced.  This gives:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it_a = std::lower_bound(x.begin(), x.end(),temp1);
int& ref_a = *it_a;
int* ptr_a = &ref_a;
```

All this can be done in a single statement, which makes the conversion trivial:

```
int *a = &*std::lower_bound(x.begin(), x.end(),temp1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a vector iterator, not a pointer to its data type, like this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator temp1;
std::vector<int>::iterator temp2;
```

Check the reference of [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) and its example for more.